# redirect output to stdout and add it to file

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to redirect the result of my 'read' command to a file (for debugging) AND to standard output (to store in DB)

The tee command, redirect to a file but don't add the output as '>>' ...

Is there a way to mix tee and >> ?

```
<?php
function readsensor($sensor) 
{ 
$output = array(); 
$return_var = 0; 
$i=1;
```

with

```
exec('/read '.$sensor.' | tee sensorlog.txt')
```

and

```
exec('/read '.$sensor.' >> sensorlog.txt')


} 
readsensor(1); 
readsensor(2); 
readsensor(3); 
?>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I'm assuming you want to append (>>) to an existing file, whilst outputting to stdout?

Tee will do this: use the '--append' argument.

You can specify multiple file names, including '-' for stdout itself, so if for whatever reason you need to output to stdout twice you can do that too.